# QFileDialog used as widget

Tags: qt, qfiledialog

My goal is: user can choose file (only *mp3) and after clicking twice on it it should play (so the QString to file should be send to play() function)
Firstly I started to work with QTreeView, but it has signal when the file is selected.

So I decided to create QFileDialog and used it as widget built-in into MainWindow.
The only problem that I have, that after double-click it disappears. It is possible to avoid it?

Should I work with some QDialog::finished() signal or, QDialog::done()?

Comment: embedding a QDialog as widget really makes awkward UI. There is QTreeView::doubleClicked( const QModelIndex& ) (inherited from QAbstractItemView) which should just do what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can get a double-click signal from QTreeView; it's:

```
void doubleClicked( const QModelIndex & index );
```

Second, if you really want to use the QFileDialog that way, first override closeEvent( QCloseEvent * event). Inside, if you want to close the dialog, do event->accept();, otherwise just do event->ignore();. Connect to QFileDialog::currentChanged( const QString & path ); to get the filename the user double-clicks. One last thing--be sure to create the QFileDialog on the heap (using new), not on the stack (a local), and call show() on it instead of exec().

Remember that you can supply it with a parent (this) and you won't need to delete it later.

Answer (score 1):

```
connect(file_dialog, SIGNAL(finished(int)), file_dialog, SLOT(open()));
```

This seems to work fine. The geometry stays fixed and it remembers the last path allright..